# How can I get metadata from boost::mysql::row?

Tags: c++, mysql, boost

How can I get metadata from an element into boost::mysql::row ?

```
void print_employee(const boost::mysql::row& employee)
    {
        std::cout << "Employee '"
                  << employee.values()[0] << std::endl;
```

how can i get metadata from here? I want to extract the column name for this specific value

```
    const boost::mysql::field_metadata &column = employee[0];
    std::cout << column.original_field_name() << std::endl;
}



    std::vector<boost::mysql::row> employees = result.read_all();
    for (const auto& employee: employees)
    {
        print_employee(employee);
    }
```

Related to this docs: https://anarthal.github.io/mysql/mysql/resultsets.html#mysql.resultsets.metadata
and this https://anarthal.github.io/mysql/

The problem is that in boost::mysql::row there isn't the property original_field_name and others because they are in ::field_metadata.

It would fine know how to connect the 2 subclass.
Surely there is a way, but I didn't found it

Comment: What is the question? You say "I want XXX" and them immediate show two lines of code that seems to do just that. Is something wrong with the code? What is wrong with it? (Do the code snippets belong together? Maybe you have a selfcontained example?)

Comment: You are right. I added more info about the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field meta data describes a rowset, not a an individual row (because in the SQL model, each row in the resultset has the exact same metadatra).

So, assuming you had a database called Test with a table Message, you can use the metadata for each row as follows:

```
#include <boost/mysql.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    boost::mysql::tcp_connection conn(ctx);

    boost::mysql::connection_params params("su", "su", "Test");
    conn.connect(tcp::endpoint{{}, boost::mysql::default_port}, params);

    auto rs = conn.query("SELECT * FROM Message;");
    std::vector<boost::mysql::field_metadata> const& meta = rs.fields();

    for (auto&& r : rs.read_all()) {
        std::cout << " ---- row:\n";
        std::vector<boost::mysql::value> const& v = r.values();

        for (size_t i = 0; i < meta.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << "\tcol:" << meta[i].original_field_name() << " val:" << v[i] << "\n";;
        }
    }
}
```

Which, on my system, prints something like

```
 ---- row:
    col:message_id val:165
    col:login_sender_id val:1
    col:login_recipient_id val:2
    col:date val:2021-02-01 02:24:22.000000
    col:content val:ahoi
    col:dialog_id val:1
    col:read_by_recipient val:1
 ---- row:
    col:message_id val:166
    col:login_sender_id val:2
    col:login_recipient_id val:1
    col:date val:2021-02-01 02:24:25.000000
    col:content val:bye
    col:dialog_id val:1
    col:read_by_recipient val:1
 ---- row:
...
etc.
```

### More Elegance

With some judicious usings/auto it becomes less cumbersome:

```
#include <boost/mysql.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using boost::asio::ip::tcp;
using boost::mysql::tcp_connection;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_context ctx;
    tcp_connection conn(ctx);

    conn.connect(tcp::endpoint{{}, boost::mysql::default_port}, {"su", "su", "Test"});

    auto rs = conn.query("SELECT * FROM Message;");
    auto& meta = rs.fields();

    for (auto&& r : rs.read_all()) {
        std::cout << " ---- row:\n";
        auto& v = r.values();

        for (size_t i = 0; i < meta.size(); ++i) {
            std::cout << "\tcol:" << meta[i].original_field_name() << " val:" << v[i] << "\n";;
        }
    }
}
```

### Cherry On Top

To make it less crummy to work with integer indexing, you can hide all that in a view:

```
auto meta_view(resultset& rs) {
    auto all = std::make_shared<std::vector<row> >(rs.read_all());
    auto row_view = [meta = rs.fields(), all](row const& r) {
        return std::views::iota(0ul, meta.size()) |
            std::views::transform([&](size_t idx) {
                   return std::tie(r.values()[idx], meta[idx]);
               });
    };
    return *all | std::views::transform(row_view);
}
```

> *Note, this plays tricks to solve issues with lifetime and the result is **not** very efficient. So, maybe just accept the crummy-ness of the interface and take this example as inspiration for other things*

Now the client code can be

```
auto rs = conn.query("SELECT * FROM Message;");

for (auto&& r : meta_view(rs)) {
    std::cout << " ---- row:\n";
    for (auto&& [val, meta] : r) {
        std::cout << "\tcol:" << meta.original_field_name()
                  << " val:" << val << "\n";
    }
}
```

Still printing the same output. (std::ranges requires c++20)

Comment: How come everything I search and find something boost related, sehe is here :)